# Mongoose add condition in Select

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to get specific fields in mongoose based on a condition. This is the case scenario I want
This is the data:

```json
{
    ...
    businessInfo: {
        isBusinessVerified: true
        categories: [...]
    }
    ...
}
```

and I want when isBusinessVerified is true to return the whole `businessInfo` object and if not return only `businessInfo` with `isBusinessVerified` field

Here is my implementation for now:

```js
    const condition = {
      ...
      businessInfo: {
        $cond: [
          {
            $eq: ['$businessInfo.isBusinessVerified', true],
          },
          '$businessInfo',
          '$$REMOVE',
        ],
      },
    };
    const userData = await userProvider.findOne({ _id: userId }, condition);
```

Also, This is working but I'm not getting `businessInfo` with `isBusinessVerified` inside it only.
And I'm getting this error However its working `server error:  Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually on the right track to use `$cond` to wrangle your businessInfo object. Just put the simple case(i.e. only the flag is returned) in `else` should be fine.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "businessInfo": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": "$businessInfo.isBusinessVerified",
          "then": "$businessInfo",
          "else": {
            businessInfo: {
              isBusinessVerified: "$businessInfo.isBusinessVerified"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4ciMVvueacp) for your reference.